# Using specific part of a HTML5 CSS3 Bootstrap template in another template

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, jquery-ui-slider

I am designing my own website by modifying multiple free templates. Some times, I need a part of template B to be included in template A. For instance, I need the "Client Logo Slider" part of the  template 2 in my original template. I copied the related HTML & CSS parts into my Index.html & main.css respectively. But where to put the JS related parts?

Which parts of the codes in main.js should I include? What is the logic behind that?

Also can you please introduce some references regarding this issue?

Comment: Man you should try Angular (4), building with blocks (components) is just the way it works.

Comment: But my templates are static! Simple Responsive HTML5!

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with multiple templates then there are possibility to break the UI you needed with other template.

In your case its better to use it in following way

1. Use template 1 as base which has rich UI controls
2. Use template 2 plugins in template 1

Include css files in header and js files in footer file.

Comment: Both templates has main.js. The point here is that I want only one part of template B to be used in template A (main theme). Can I include two main.js in footer?

Comment: I think you didn't get my point 
Just try to identify plugin used in template B
Then use that plugin in Template A 

Reason : 

both main.js may have same selectors and methods that can overwrite with 2nd main. js in order they are included